# Determine whether a type is used in an assembly

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, .net-4.5, .net-assembly

Assume for a moment I have an arbitrary managed assembly called `Acme.Core.dll`. How can I determine whether a type, say XmlSerializer, is being used anywhere in the assembly?

In essence, I'd like to verify compiled assemblies against predefined polices. In the case of XmlSerializer, I want to verify whether there is an assembly `Acme.Core.XmlSerializers.dll`. Another use case may prohibit the use of certain types, say BCL to deal with MD5, or the use of System.IO types, like File or Directory.

In case you wonder why such policies may exist, well, in a highly regulated or secure environment, any data at rest should be encrypted. The use of weak cryptography algorithms is not permitted.

Comment: I'm curious why it be voted down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use Code Access Security Policy I think. It's old-school but as far as I know, it works.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648243.aspx